# Time stamp information in BLE Beacon packets

Tags: ibeacon, beacon

I have a requirement that in BLE Beacon Packets, I want to send the time stamp information with in Beacon packets . My questions are : 
1. Is it possible to include time stamp in BLE beacon packets ? .
2. If we can send the time stamp information with in Beacon packets , where exactly i should store this information in payload ? . UUID ?

Answer (score 1):

You do not have many bytes to work with in a BLE beacon packet.  The max data payload is about 20-25 bytes, but if using iBeacon on iOS this drops drastically to 4 bytes because the 16 byte UUID portion of that beacon format takes of 16 of 24 of the readable data bytes, and the full UUID must be fixed and specified to the OS up front.

So on iOS you can use the 4 byte major/minor combo to store a timestamp.  This would store a time value in seconds since 1970 that would not roll over until about the year 2136.

Comment: Thanks for your reply David. I was thinking that we can store this time stamp info in UUID which is of 16 bytes long( I thought I can make use of some 6 bytes here which will be a part of UUID .Since I will be adding time stamp in the UUID , UUID will be changing every minute . ) . Is UUID has to be fixed all the time ? .

Comment: If you want to detect on iOS, UUID must be fixed, yes.